# How do I test Django views when they don't return values

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-testing

I'm new to Django.  I've worked through some tutorials, written some models, views, forms etc. but I don't understand how they can be tested since either nothing is returned, or whatever is returned is so tightly bound it doesn't make sense in terms of the test.

For example here are two view classes:

```
class ListBlogPostView(ListView):
    model = BlogPost
    template_name = 'app/blogpost_list.html'


class CreateBlogPostView(CreateView):
    model = BlogPost
    template_name = 'app/blogpost_edit.html'
    form_class = BlogPostForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('blogpost-list')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CreateBlogPostView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['action'] = reverse('blogpost-new')
        return context
```

The first, ListBlogPostView, doesn't return anything.  How can I ever check that this is working correctly?

The second has a couple of functions but their return values are not things I can test with an assert

How could I ever use a TDD approach to Django?

I'm used to using nunit and MS 'unit' tests in Visual Studio, mocking etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, Django's **generic** class-based views are not called generic for no reason.

You can view the source of the both [`ListView`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/list.py#L139) and [`CreateView`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py#L160).

---

The `ListView` has a *GET* method handler:

```
class BaseListView(MultipleObjectMixin, View):
    """A base view for displaying a list of objects."""
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
        allow_empty = self.get_allow_empty()

        if not allow_empty:
           # ...

        context = self.get_context_data()
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

Which returns a valid Django response and can be tested in `tests.py`.

---

If you look at the `CreateView`, it inherits from `BaseCreateView` (just like `ListView` inherits from `BaseListView`):

```
class BaseCreateView(ModelFormMixin, ProcessFormView):
    """
    Base view for creating an new object instance.
    Using this base class requires subclassing to provide a response mixin.
    """
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # ...

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # ...
```

Which also inherits from [`ProcessFormView`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py#L129):

```
class ProcessFormView(View):
    """Render a form on GET and processes it on POST."""
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """Handle GET requests: instantiate a blank version of the form."""
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Handle POST requests: instantiate a form instance with the passed
        POST variables and then check if it's valid.
        """
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
```

The *GET* request will result in a valid response. As you see, the *POST* method handler here returns either `self.form_valid(form)` or `self.form_invalid(form)` depending on the form status.

You can see the source of these two methods in [`ViewMixin`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py#L55):

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    """If the form is valid, redirect to the supplied URL."""
    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

def form_invalid(self, form):
    """If the form is invalid, render the invalid form."""
    return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

Both of these methods return a valid *testable* Django responses.

---

In conclusion, both of your `ListBlogPostView` and `CreateBlogPostView` can be directly tested in `tests.py`. You just need to have a more detailed look at [the implementation of Django's generic views](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/views/generic). *The power of open-source!*

Comment: This is fantastic!  I didn't know that I could see under the hood and get the source of the built-in Django methods.  It makes everything a lot clearer, thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Testing `view` unlike function most of the time will not have a return value. The way that I go about doing it is to assert the `html` response.

So for the `ListBlogPostView` it depends on what is in the `blogpost_list.html` template.

A general view test should look like this:

```
class ListBlogPostViewTest(TestCase):

    def test_blogpost_list_view(self): 
        response = self.client.get(reverse('blogpost-list'))
        html = response.content.decode('utf8')  
        self.assertTrue(html.startswith('<html>'))
        self.assertIn('<title>BlogPost lists</title>', html)  
        self.assertTrue(html.endswith('</html>'))
```

For `view` that have `context` you can actually check if it is being retrieved and passed correctly to view.

```
blogPost = BlogPost.object.get(id=1)
self.assertEqual(response.context['blogPost'].name, blogPost.name)
```

> How could I ever use a TDD approach to Django?

As for TDD, you just have to test the `html` view first before creating it. It really depend on how detail you like to test and find the balance for it. I prefer to test mainly on the `context` being set and important `html` element is in the `view`.

Comment: Thanks very much for this.  There's nothing to beat an actual example of how to put together a solution

Answer (score 0):

You can still surely test lot of parameters -

- status code on get and post request
- variables in context data (such as form)
- assert template used
- creation of object on post request in case of create view
- check for permissions using status codes

The thing is tests on django views are technically integration tests. As long as your tests are granular enough, means you don't test code for forms or models in views, I don't see any problem provided you follow Classical TDD.

Comment: It didn't occur to me to assert the template, check permissions etc., that's a great idea